# Angular and firebase dropdown list to filter dinamically

Tags: json, angularjs, html, firebase

I have an app that has a list of achievements.A user can add achievement from within the app. An achievement is a json object stored in firebase and looks like this:

```
 achv_date: "2 February, 2015"
 achv_department:
         digitalInnovation: "digitalInnovation"
         example:"example"
 achv_type: "example"
 date: 1422828000000
 description: "fsafa"
 image: "data:image/j"
 name: "dsa"
```

And this is the department json object that is getting displayed dinamically into a list of checkbox that a user can select and then they are also shown in a dropdown for the user to make the filter on them:
 `departments
 Finance: "Finance"
 HR: "HR"
 digital innovation: "digital innovation"
 example: "example"
 marketing:"marketing"`

I have this dropdown in my application with which I'm making a filter. So what department the user select only those achievements will be displayed. 
My html dropdown looks like this:

```
<ul id='dropdown3' class='dropdown-content'>
<li  ng-repeat="department in departments"><a ng-click="filterBy(department)">{{department.$value}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

The `filterBy()` method in the controller looks like this:

```
$scope.filterBy = function(checkbox){
 $scope.department = {};
 $scope.department.achv_department = {};
 $scope.department.achv_department = Object.defineProperty($scope.department.achv_department, checkbox.$id, {value: checkbox.$value});
        }
```

I also have this code which works in a way, but it actually checks the value that the user selects and looks for it in all of the achievement proprieties. I want the `filterBy` method to look only in the `department` property but I can't figure out how to make the dinamically part of the model work

```
$scope.filterBy = function(checkbox){
            $scope.department = checkbox.$value;
   }
```

Any ideas are much apreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the problem like this:

```
$scope.filterBy = function(checkbox){
            $scope.department = {};
            $scope.department[checkbox.$id] = checkbox.$value;
        }
```

and added this line in html:

```
<li id="item" class="col s12 m6 l4" ng-repeat="(key, meeting) in meetings  | filter:{achv_department : department}" spinner-on-load>
```